# Maths in LaTex table of contents

Tags: math, latex

I am trying to add a table of contents for my LaTex document. The issue I am having is that this line:

```
    \subsubsection{The expectation of \(X^2\)}
```

Causes an error in the file that contains the table of contents

```
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}
The expectation of \relax $X^2\relax \GenericError { }{
LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter}{
    See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.}
{Your command was ignored.\MessageBreak Type I <command> <return> 
to replace it with another command,\MessageBreak or <return> to 
continue without it.}}{5}
```

Which causes the document not to be generated.

Does anyone have a solution to having maths in sections while still having the table of contents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the Amsmath inline math delimiter `$` instead of `\(` and `\)`. Thus:

```
\subsubsection{The expectation of $X^2$}
```

**Note:** be sure to remove the currently generated `.toc` file first, otherwise the error will not go away.

Comment: Is there any downside to using $ and $$ as opposed to \\( and \\[?

Comment: `$` is fine, but `\[`...`\]` should always be used over `$$`...`$$`.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to continue using `\(`...`\)` as your math delimiters, you can load the (officially supported) `fixltx2e` package. This is where fixes to LaTeX go that cannot be integrated into the main sources because of the possibility of backwards compatibility problems.

(In short, your problem is that `\(` and `\)` by default aren't "robust" and hence can't be used in places like section headings and captions; the fixltx2e package fixes this.)

Answer (score 1):

Could you try again with putting the $ signs around the expression? What error do you get?